# java dom parser only gets the first entity

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

This code returs only one "question " tag's element but I have another 9 question element inside the xml file.What is the wrong thing in here?Do I need to loop.Because when I checked the loop, it loops only one time.What is the problem?I am figure out.

Here is my xml:

```
<Results>
  <question>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>1</qno>
    <qtext>The Battle of Gettysburg was fought during which war?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>C</correctAnswer>
  </question>
  <question>
    <eno>3</eno>
    <qno>2</qno>
    <qtext>Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin walked how many 
minutes on the moon in 1696?</qtext>
    <correctAnswer>B</correctAnswer>
  </question> 
</Results>
```

my source code:

```
NodeList listOfQuestions = doc.getElementsByTagName("question");
for(int s=0; s<listOfQuestions.getLength(); s++)
        {
            System.out.println(listOfQuestions.getLength());
            Node firstQuestionNode = listOfQuestions.item(0);
            if(firstQuestionNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element firstQElement = (Element)firstQuestionNode;

                NodeList enoList = firstQElement.getElementsByTagName("eno");
                Element enoElement =(Element)enoList.item(s);
                NodeList enosList = enoElement.getChildNodes();
                String eno=((Node)enosList.item(s)).getNodeValue().trim();
                System.out.println(eno);

                NodeList qnoList = firstQElement.getElementsByTagName("qno");
                Element qnoElement =(Element)qnoList.item(s);
                NodeList qnosList = qnoElement.getChildNodes();
                String qno= ((Node)qnosList.item(s)).getNodeValue().trim();
                System.out.println(qno);

                NodeList qtextList = firstQElement.getElementsByTagName("qtext");
                Element qtextElement =(Element)qtextList.item(s);
                NodeList qtextsList = qtextElement.getChildNodes();
                String qtext= ((Node)qtextsList.item(s)).getNodeValue().trim();
                System.out.println(qtext);

                NodeList correctAnswerList = firstQElement.getElementsByTagName("correctAnswer");
                Element correctAnswerElement =(Element)correctAnswerList.item(s);
                NodeList correctAnswerElementList = correctAnswerElement.getChildNodes();
                String correctAnswer= ((Node)correctAnswerElementList.item(s)).getNodeValue().trim();
                System.out.println(correctAnswer);

                int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into question(eno,qno,qtext,correctAnswer) values('"+eno+"','"+qno+"','"+qtext+"','"+correctAnswer+"')");
                System.out.println("s is"+s);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded

```
Node firstQuestionNode = listOfQuestions.item(0);
                                             ^^^
```

I think you meant to use the variable `s` there... or maybe not, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Regardless, there are no other references to `listOfQuestions` and you never retrieve any node except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), it is an API specifically built for parsing HTML DOM code in java and has tons of extra features. Also, what you are currently trying to extract would not be more than just 3-4 LOC using the API components.

Look at their example on their website for connection to an URL and fetching DOM-Elements is just 2 LOC:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```